# Storing instances of an array using the slice method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array *list* I loop over and modify it each time. I want to store all instances of my *list* array in an other array I named *allLists*, and to do so, I'm using the slice method.

It seems to work in the simple example below:

```
let list=[1,2,3,4];
let allList = [];

allList.push(list.slice());

list[2]=6;
allList.push(list.slice());

console.log(allList);// returns [1,2,3,4] [1,2,6,4]
```

But it doesn't work in the following code. Instead, *allLists* is filled with the last instance of the *list* array.

```js
let list = Array.from({
  length: 9
}, () => Array.from({
  length: 9
}, () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
let allLists = [list.slice()];
let indexList = [];
let lengthList = [];
let key = true;

function handleNewIndex(list) {
  let newIndex = [0, 0];
  let maxLength = 9;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
      if (list[i][j].length < maxLength && list[i][j].length > 0) {
        maxLength = list[i][j].length;
        newIndex = [i, j];
      }
    }
  }
  return newIndex;
}

function isSudokuValid(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
      if (list[i][j].length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function handleWrongSudoku(allLists, indexList, lengthList) {
  let counter = 1;
  while (lengthList[lengthList.length - counter] <= 1) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    allLists.pop();
    indexList.pop();
  }
  let wrongList = allLists.pop();
  list = allLists.pop();
  indexLine = indexList[indexList.length - 1][0];
  indexColumn = indexList[indexList.length - 1][1];
  let wrongNumber = wrongList[indexLine][indexColumn];
  for (let i = 0; i < list[indexLine][indexColumn].length; i++) {
    if (list[indexLine][indexColumn][i] != wrongNumber) {
      list[indexLine][indexColumn] = list[indexLine][indexColumn][i];
    }
  }
  allLists.push(list.slice());
  indexLine = handleNewIndex(list)[0];
  indexColumn = handleNewIndex(list)[1];
}

function generateSudoku() {
  let indexLine = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  let indexColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < 81) {
    indexList.push([indexLine, indexColumn]);
    let bigSquareIndex = 3 * Math.floor(indexLine / 3) + Math.floor(indexColumn / 3);
    lengthList.push(list[indexLine][indexColumn].length);
    list[indexLine][indexColumn] = list[indexLine][indexColumn][Math.floor(Math.random() * list[indexLine][indexColumn].length)];
    counter = counter + 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (3 * Math.floor(i / 3) + Math.floor(j / 3) === bigSquareIndex) {
          let k = 0;
          let n = list[i][j].length;
          while (list[i][j][k] != list[indexLine][indexColumn] && k < n) {
            k = k + 1;
          }
          if (k < n) {
            list[i][j].splice(k, 1);
          }
        } else if (i === indexLine || j === indexColumn) {
          let k = 0;
          let n = list[i][j].length;
          while (list[i][j][k] != list[indexLine][indexColumn] && k < n) {
            k = k + 1;
          }
          if (k < n) {
            list[i][j].splice(k, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allLists.push(list.slice());
    key = isSudokuValid(list);
    if (key === false) { //ignore this scenario, not done yet, assume key = true at all time
      console.log(key, lengthList, indexList, allLists);
      handleWrongSudoku(allLists, indexList, lengthList);
      key = true;
      //return;
    } else {
      indexLine = handleNewIndex(list)[0];
      indexColumn = handleNewIndex(list)[1];
    }
  }
}

generateSudoku();
console.log(allLists); // returns 81 times the same 9x9 array instead of the 81 different instances of the list array
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: hint :- slice creates a shallow copy, whereas your list is two level deep, you need to create a deep copy

Comment: your logic within if and else-if is entirely the same. How can you expect it to give different lists?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint Code Maniac.

I used the JSON method instead to create a deep copy and it's working fine now.

```
allLists.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)));
```

This post explains the difference between shallow and deep copy:

> https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/

Comment: This is a good example of code that is physically painful to see.